# Simple TCP EchoServer in Python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I found this script of TCP server which "echoes" back the data to the client.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import socket

host = ''
port = 50000
backlog = 5 
size = 1024 
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
s.bind((host,port)) 
s.listen(backlog) 
while 1: 
    client, address = s.accept() 
    data = client.recv(size) 
    if data: 
        client.send(data) 
    client.close()
```

I'm trying to test & understand it before I will be able to do something on my own and modify, but I'm having some problems. When I'm trying to run the .py script I get the following error in my Terminal (using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "echo.py", line 14, in <module>
    s.bind((host,port))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

My Python version is 2.7.6

is there something wrong with the code or I'm doing something wrong?

**UPDATE:**

it gets worse, any script I run with `bind(host, port)` gives me the  **same**  error.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try using a different value for `port`.

Comment: @AlexHall that was my first guess as well, I tried like 10 different ones but error is still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you accidentally ran the EchoServer twice in different windows?  You can only bind one receiver to a port/address combination.

Comment: this gave me a thought, I didn't exactly do that, but I might have done it, meaning: when I start terminal and run the script for the first time nothing happens, literally. So, I terminated the process by `Crtl+Z` and ran the script again, it worked (gave me the error) is it possible that the process caused by first ran is still on ? I have no idea, the thing is that no matter how long I wait nothing happens when I first run the script in terminal.

Comment: On a Linux system, ctrl-z will push the process into the background.  So it's probably still running.  Check with the ps command.

Comment: o yea, it's still running... I get it now, this part of the problem solved, thanks ! But, still, I can't run the script, it just hangs, any idea about this?

Comment: Has it hung? The script is meant to go into a permanent loop echoing data back to a client.  It doesn't print anything out on the server screen, only reply to the client.

Comment: right... can I make it so that, I run it as a client and whatever I type I get back from the server ?

Comment: Start the server running, then open another terminal and do "telnet 127.0.0.1 50000", then you'll be connected to the server.  Whatever you type will be echoed to you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is some other application running on those ports.

Can you try checking if there are any other app listening on same port using:

```
netstat -ntlpu | grep 50000
```

Comment: `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6735/python `

this is the output.

Comment: Try checking what process is PID 6735, if you dont have root access, why don't you get assistance from sysadmin and check what process it that.

Answer (score 0):

To bind a server it's a little confusing but you have to use a tuple. The correct way is `server.bind((host, port))`